# Why does Minecraft get stuck downloading 'guava-17.0.jar'?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

My copy of Minecraft seems to get stuck on 'guava-17.0.jar' when I try to download it, and it's always that.

I looked up everywhere how to fix the problem of the launcher staying stuck on this "Downloading guava-17.0.jar".

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: did you try reinstalling your minecraft?

Comment: The title seems different than the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

As @KenzoEngineer said in the, try re-installing Minecraft! (Delete .minecraft folder)

Comment: If he answers I will be happy to remove my answer!